# Does azure charge only for new storage every month

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Let's suppose I keep adding 5 GB of data every month. I understand that the first month cost will be based on capacity of 5GB and operations performed on that data. But now if next month I add, say 5GB more, would I be charged for a capacity of 10GB or only the new storage (5GB)?

As per my understanding cost of operations (read/write/tier-change) are on the size of data but what confuses me is the storage capacity, if I am billed for the **cumulative capacity** or just the **new storage**.

Please suggest and thanks in advance!!

(**Note:** I am already planning to apply tier level automation on the unused data, above query is out of curiosity and confusion on the billing specs mentioned here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/storage/blobs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re charged for the cumulative space.

Taking your example, for the first month you’ll not be charged anything as you’ve only stored 5GB data.

In the 2nd month you added 5GB more so the total data stored is 10GB. Considering first 5GB is free, you’ll only be charged for 5GB.

**UPDATE**

To answer your additional questions

> So lets suppose the storage for the first month is over the free tier,
> say 5TB and 5TB more the next month, now the capacity cost next month
> is on 10TB or just the 5TB?

Storage costs are calculated on the total amount of data stored. In this case you will be charged for 10TB as the total amount of data stored in that month is 10TB (5TB from previous month + 5TB in the current month).

> if I keep storing 5TB every month, it would be significantly more than
> the case where I keep archiving the old 5TB every month, is that so

That is correct. I am assuming that by `archiving` you mean that you will be moving the data in `archive` access tier. Please note that you will still be charged for the data that is there in the `archive` access tier. It's just that you will be charged lesser for the data that's there in that tier but you will be charged as Azure Storage is storing that data for you.

To stop paying for the data storage costs, you will need to delete the data.

Comment: So lets suppose the storage for the first month is over the free tier, say 5TB and 5TB more the next month, now the capacity cost next month is on 10TB or just the 5TB? as per the pricing chart, it talks just about the monthly capacity but it seems if I keep storing 5TB every month, it would be significantly more than the case where I keep archiving the old 5TB every month, is that so?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks :)